# raspberry picamera throwing error PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 128x80

Tags: python, raspicam

I've been running my camera for nearly over a month now, with brief halting throughout the past month, but recently I noticed my picamera was not taking any pictures, I checked the script and it was failing at:

```
PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 128x80
```

Here is my `python` 2.7 code:

```
testWidth = 128
testHeight = 80

def takeDayImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, filename):
    if verbose:
        print "takeDayImage - Working ....."
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
        camera.resolution = (imageWidth, imageHeight)
        # camera.rotation = cameraRotate #Note use imageVFlip and imageHFlip variables
        if imagePreview:
            camera.start_preview()
        camera.vflip = imageVFlip
        camera.hflip = imageHFlip
        # Day Automatic Mode
        camera.exposure_mode = 'auto'
        camera.iso = dayISO
        camera.awb_mode = 'auto'
        camera.capture(filename)
        camera.led = True #False
    if verbose:
        print "takeDayImage - Captured %s" % (filename)
        camera.truncate(0) #added 07-30-17
    return filename

def motionDetection():
    print "Scanning for Motion threshold=%i sensitivity=%i ......"  % (threshold, sensitivity)
    print "Successfully loaded detectmotion.py"
    isDay = True
    currentCount= 1000
    while True:
        if scanMotion(testWidth, testHeight, isDay):
            filename = getFileName(imagePath, imageNamePrefix, currentCount)
            if numberSequence:
                currentCount += 1
            if isDay:
                takeDayImage( imageWidth, imageHeight, filename )
            else:
                takeNightImage( imageWidth, imageHeight, filename )
```

I had read to call the `.truncate()` method and have implemented it, after researching this exact error (as stated above), but it still seems to be having this same error.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried changing the width and height to 1080x720 and then crop it?
It could be that the camera has a minimum size.

Comment: @MathiasLindström  tried that but the error changes then to: `PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 1080x720` . any other thoughts? still stuck

Comment: Could you pastebin the whole code?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be:

```
imageDir = "westmontavecamimage"
imagePath = "/media/pi/StoyAveCamStorag/" + imageDir
```

Does a great job on my Pi.
You could check if Python has read/write rights if that doesn't solve the problem for you.

Comment: how does thus present a problem? the full path of `imagePath` doesnt end with `/`

Comment: @Jshee: If the path isn't correct. It won't be able to save the pictures.